# Exposed Taxonomy filter relationship with two levels

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have searched about that but I didn't found any solution for my problem, I also tried to combine different solutions that I found but didn't work.

Those solutions were different combinations of what I mention on this post (for eg. 2 relationship and contextual filter, one relationship with contextual filter, only contextual filter, on filter criteria add "has taxonomy term", "term ID" etc.

I have taxonomy terms with childrens

Car

- BMW
- FIAT
- VW

Motorcycle

- Yamaha
- Honda
- Kawasaki

I created page view with filter criteria like this
[image: filter criteria]

My output is this:

[image: output]

Until here is everything works perfectly.

Now I want a brand subfilter.

So I filter by "car" and the result is all car brands (bmw, fiat and vw), after that I want to choose "bmw" or "fiat" or "vw" and the result will be all cars with choosen brand.

I have added another filter criteria:

[image: brand filter]

And my output is:

[image: output with 2 filters]

Now I want:

- when I choose "car" show me all cars (works)
- when I choose "car" and "BMW" show me all BMW cars (not working)

Instead I have no results.

If I don't group second filter criteria (brands) this works as expected BUT I have a select list with all options (car, bmw, fiat, vw, motorcycle, yamaha, honda, kawasaki), but I don't want this, I only want the car brands.

There is a way to show on a select list only brands(bmw, fiat and vw) instead of all options? I could work with this.

I tried different configurations on brand filter criteria, group them (is one of, is all of, etc).

Also tried to create a relationship by term, create another relationship (parent) and contextual filter "taxonomy term: parent terms" but didn't work these 3 together. Tried only with one relationship but didn't work. Tried only with contextual filter and didn't work.

I always get no results.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe an alternative: https://www.drupal.org/project/shs

Comment: `Any help` unfortunately is a too broad request. The question also is missing what exactly you've tried so far and what exactly didn't work. We need to know this beforehand to prevent giving you answers you already know. Please edit your question accordingly. Many thanks

Comment: @leymannx I have explained what I have done and what works and not. It works for the first "step" when I create "has taxonomy term (group by parent)", so when I choose "car" show me all the cars. Didn't work brand subfilter, created "has taxonomy term (group)", also create relationship by term, relationship by parent and contextual filter "taxonomy term: parent terms". Thats what I have tried, I found these solutions on other topics but didn't work. Without that haven't tried nothing new. I don't know how to explain more/better

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to `I also tried to combine different solutions that I found but didn't work`.

Comment: @leymannx I mention those solutions, one was with 2 relationship and contextual filter, another was only one relationship and contextual filter, other was only with contextual filter, so I tried to combine different methods/configurations with those I have mention on original post. I will edit my post to be more "understandable" :)